# Python 3: match names from a text file and print them out line by line

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My goal is to print out the matches line by line from a text file that my reular expression will match. My file regexprc.txt has all kinds of stuff written in it, but I want to write a simple program that will just match names from that file and print each one of them line by line.

The rule is : lines that have a first and last name with an optional middle name all separated by one whitespace, any first letter must be capitalized, and any alphabetic string is acceptable for as a name. So it should match John Smith, John Lee Smith, A B, A B C, Abc Def Z. It should not match john Smith, a Z, Ab Cd EE, A B C D.

Unfortunately I need some help with this as I'm new to Python 3. Here's what I tried so far:

```
import re

file_read = open("regexprc.txt", "r")
#match names
ptr = '^([A-Z][a-z]*\s){1,2}([A-Z][a-z]*)?$'

for line in file_read:
    a = re.search(ptr, line)
    print(a)
```

This code only prints a lot of `None` statements along with some messages that look like :

```
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='A B\n'>.
```

Once again I just want it to print out the names in `regexprc.txt` line by line.

Comment: I highly recommend that you read the docs for `re.search` to see what it returns. It is spelled out *quite* clearly there. There is no reason to ask this on SO since any correct answer will just be a rehash of those docs.

Comment: Use  `a = re.search(ptr, line)` and then `if a:` // `print(a.group())`

Comment: Your regex is slightly more restrictive than your criteria.  Should your regex accept the string `Liam MacDonald`?

Comment: Wiktor thank you but can you please explain the if a: statement. What I know is that a should meet a certain condition, but you just wrote if a: . Could you please explain??

Comment: `if a:` treats `a` as a boolean. `None` is considered false, and a valid match is considered true, so this only shows lines which match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

ptr = r'your_regular_expression'

with open('your_file_name', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for match in re.finditer(ptr, line):
            print(match.group())
```

This will find all matches within each line, and print out "group 0" (that is, all the text which matched) for each of them.

The with-statement also takes care of closing the file for you, so it's good practice to use it in general.